# Variable doesn't exist

Tags: variable, error

I get "Variable `career` does not exist". I'll just go straight to the code example...

```
{# Set ECM and get the entries stored in variable "entries" #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.getAllSections('and, not career').type('news').order('RAND()').limit(3) %}

{# Conditional statement - if more entries than 0, we output them. If false, we set other conditional statement/s. #}
{% if entries|length > 0 %}

    {# Loop through entries #}
    {% for entry in entries %}      
        <li>
            {# My Stuff #}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}

    {# Set ECM and get the entries stored in variable "career" #}
    {% set career = craft.entries.section('career').type('news') %}

{% elseif career %}

    {# Loop through career #}
    {% for career in career %}      
        <li>
            {# My Stuff #}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

Is it because of the first variable `entries`?

Comment: I don't understand the question... what variable doesn't exist? What's not working as you'd expect?

Comment: I expect to load `{% elseif career %}` if, the first statement is `false`. But variable `career` doesn't exists.

Comment: @Brad Bell Thank you for clean up and indentation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting `career` **inside of** the `if` statement. Defining it there won't make it available for your `elseif` statement.

I've trimmed down your code so you can see exactly what the problem is:

```
{% set entries = ... %}

{% if entries|length > 0 %}

    {% set career = ... %}

{% elseif career %}

    ...

{% endif %}
```

If you want `career` to be available to your `elseif` statement, you need to define it **before** your `if` statement.

Comment: I was considering that, but didn't performed it. Thank  you @Lindsey D

Comment: You are welcome! I was reviewing the edit history for your question, and noticed that Brad added indentation to your code example. I'm not sure if your original code also lacks indentation... Seeing it fully indented helped me find exactly where the error was. :)